# Date function for predicting future dates

Tags: excel, function, date, formula

What is the excel formula for predicting range of dates for future visits (e.g. Visit 2 is Day 29  +/- 3 days from Day 1) with Day 1 visit given as a specific date (e.g. December 4, 2013)

Comment: What? can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve? Its unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

With a date in cell **A1**, in another cell enter:

**=TEXT(A1+29-3,"mm/dd/yyyy"  ) & " - " &  TEXT(A1+29+3,"mm/dd/yyyy"  )**

Answer (score 0):

Dates are numbers in excel. You can add them:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]